# How Can I Compare a SMS code to the code stored in the Database

Tags: mysql, node.js

How Would I be able to compare a code that was inputted by the user and compare it to the code I have stored in the database.

I believe I can compare with a query but im not sure if theres a better way.

Comment: A query with a where clause like `where column_name = 'fred'` But of course using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: to interact with a database you need to query it(CRUD operations). What do you mean by a better way?